# How to remove duplicates from collection using IEqualityComparer, LinQ Distinct

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am unable to remove the duplicates from collection , i have implemented IEqualityComparer for the class Employee still i am not getting the output

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Employe> Employeecollection = new List<Employe>();

        Employeecollection.Add(new Employe("abc","def"));
        Employeecollection.Add(new Employe("lmn","def"));
        Employeecollection.Add(new Employe("abc", "def"));

        IEnumerable<Employe> coll = Employeecollection.Distinct(new Employe());

        foreach (Employe item in coll)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.fName + "   " + item.lName );
        }

    }
```

The Below is the Employee class implementation , here i implemented IEqualityComparer

```
class Employe : IEqualityComparer<Employe>
{
    public string fName { get; set; }
    public string lName { get; set; }

    public Employe()
    {

    }

    public Employe(string firstName, string LastName)
    {
        this.fName = firstName;
        this.lName = LastName;
    }

    #region IEqualityComparer<pcf> Members

    public bool Equals(Employe x, Employe y)
    {
        if (x.fName == y.fName && x.lName == y.lName)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Employe obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Forget IEqualityComparer and just use Linq directly:

```
EmployeeCollection.GroupBy(x => new{x.fName, x.lName}).Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: Can u please explain the above one i understand GroupBy but what is Select(g => g.First()

Comment: The GroupBy operation will return you an IEnumerable of [IGrouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) items (which are IEnumerables as well). In the case of your example, there will be two items in the outer IEnumerable: one IGrouping with two entries for each "abc", "def"; another IGrouping with one entry for "lmn", "def". The First() operator will take the first item out of the inner IGrouping IEnumerables.

Comment: for logic with multiple properties, you have to group on all properties which will run slower than the xor comparison.

Comment: @NikolaMitev: Using XOR to calculate hashes can cause collisions when hashing over values that have a small range such as enums. While collisions don't affect the correctness of hash-table-like operations, they make them more expensive. The c# compiler automatically writes a much better implementation of GetHashCode for anonymous objects that is considerably less likely to collide. I'd argue that while using XOR might be computationally cheap, a better implementation is also very light on computation and will have benefits beyond the calculation of the the hash code.

Comment: @NikolaMitev: Actual comparison of properties will only occur when there are collisions in the collection that is hashed. GroupBy still uses hashes in the same way as Distinct. I think your comment above is misleading.

Comment: @spender, so your code will only return Employees that have a unique combination of both first and last names? (Namely: 1x "ABC DEF" and 1x "LMN DEF" ?)

Answer (score 5):

You need to override `GetHashCode` method in your Employee. You haven't done this. One example of a good hashing method is given below: (generated By [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/))

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return ((this.fName != null ? this.fName.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ (this.lName != null ? this.lName.GetHashCode() : 0);
}
```

now after `Distinct` is called, foreach loop prints:

```
abc   def
lmn   def
```

In your case you are calling object's class `GetHashCode`, which knows nothing about internal fields.

One simple note, [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) contains [DistinctBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs?r=d4396b9ff63932be0ab07c36452a481d20f96307) extension method, which allows you to do:

```
IEnumerable<Employe> coll = 
 Employeecollection.DistinctBy(employee => new {employee.fName, employee.lName});
```

Anonymous objects have correct implementation for both `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)

```
    public int GetHashCode(Employe obj)
    {
        return obj.fname.GetHashCode() ^ obj.lname.GetHashCode();
    }
```

Comment: You should never implement GetHashCode without also implementing equality members. GetHashCode should also be an override. Also worth remembering that *"'xor' can create or exacerbate distribution problems when there is redundancy in data structures."* : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The hashcode implementation is not correct:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return 13 * fName.GetHashCode() + 7 * lName.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: is it ok to receive `NullReferenceException` in `GetHashCode`, when one of the objects fields is null?

Comment: It definitely isn't - I just thought I could clarify that "hashcodes should be same when equals are same" fact, than focus on the null checks. But yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Also it looks like your comparing by reference instead of content, hence the compare function doesn't work.

change it to use .Equals() instead of == and it should work.
example below:

```
#region IEqualityComparer<pcf> Members

public bool Equals(Employe x, Employe y)
{
    if (x.fName.Equals(y.fName) && x.lName.Equals(y.lName))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public int GetHashCode(Employe obj)
{
    return obj.GetHashCode();
}

#endregion
```

Comment: The == operator works just fine for strings in c#. The problem is in the GetHashCode() implementation.

Answer (score -1):

```
public int GetHashCode(Employe obj)
{
    return obj.GetHashCode();
}
```

For this method, return a hashcode of the properties that you are comparing for equality, instead of the object itself. Comparing the hashcode of the objects will always be `false`, so your list will never be filtered for duplicates.