# Eleminate duplicates Items from a List<T> by foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach, lambda

How to eliminate the duplicate Item(Timestamp) from List of items. I have a list of  items with duplicate  timestamp. I want to fill another response List and eliminate the duplicate records on the bases of unique timestamp by For each loop. Only One timestamp should be present in return items list.

```
    public class InventoryDetails
    {
        public int InventoryDetailsId { get; set; }
        public int ItemName { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class InventoryDetailsResponse
    {
        public int InventoryDetailsId { get; set; }
        public int ItemName { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

Sample Inventory data from Database

101 , Item1, 500, **2015-06-24 16:00:03**
102 , Item2, 125, 2015-07-01 01:20:03
103 , Item1, 500, **2015-06-24 16:00:03**
104 , Item3, 340, 2015-07-04 09:10:12
105 , Item4, 059, 2015-06-24 12:23:03
106 , Item1, 500, **2015-06-24 16:00:03**
107 , Item5, 845, 2015-07-11 15:30:03

// Need to remove the duplicate records on the bases of timestamp.

```
public List<InventoryDetailsResponse> GetInventory()
        {
            List<InventoryDetails> result = FromDatabase();
            var list = new List<InventoryDetailsResponse>();

            foreach (InventoryDetails match in result)
            {
                var tc = new InventoryDetailsResponse
                {
                    InventoryDetailsId = match.InventoryDetailsId,
                    ItemName = match.ItemName,
                    Price = match.Price,
                    Timestamp = match.Timestamp  // Duplicate timestamp in database.
                };
                list.Add(tc);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to eliminate duplicates in memory or inside the query?

Comment: If you want to do it after the query, you can create a HashSet<DateTime>, add each time stamp in your foreach and add a condition around list.Add to check whether the timestamp hasn't already been met

Answer (score 5):

Use Linq directly:

```
var myUniqueRecordsByTimestamp = GetInventory()
                                .GroupBy(x => x.Timestamp)
                                .Select(g => g.First());
```

The `GroupBy` operation will return you an `IEnumerable` of `IGrouping` items (which are `IEnumerables` as well).

[Source Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983618/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-collection-using-iequalitycomparer-linq-distinct) from similar but yet not duplicate question.

Comment: This is the first sensible answer which doesn't break `Equals` for the object and does what the OP probably actually wants...

Comment: If the OP needs to de-duplicate records based on a timestamp, the thing the OP most likely wants is to sob uncontrollably.

Comment: @susheeltyagi, No problem mate :), if it helped you, consider Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this for the same purpose, works like a charm:

```
List<InventoryDetails> list = result.GroupBy(x => x.Timestamp).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();
```

It groups the items according to the specified property (here, Timestamp) and builds a new list using the first item of each group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
public List<InventoryDetailsResponse> GetInventory()
{
    List<InventoryDetails> result = FromDatabase();
    var list = new List<InventoryDetailsResponse>();

    foreach (InventoryDetails match in result)
    {
        var tc = new InventoryDetailsResponse
        {
            InventoryDetailsId = match.InventoryDetailsId,
            ItemName = match.ItemName,
            Price = match.Price,
            Timestamp = match.Timestamp  // Duplicate timestamp in database.
        };
        list.Add(tc);
     }

    var res = list.GroupBy(item => item.Timestamp).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can override `Equals` for your `InventoryDetails` class, like:

```
class InventoryDetails {
    public override Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj is InventoryDetails) {
            InventoryDetails details = (InventoryDetails)obj;
            return details.ItemName == this.ItemName && details.Price == this.Price && details.Timestamp == this.Timestamp;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

After that, you can just use `List<InventoryDetails>.Distinct()` to remove duplicate entries, as all entries, which have the same `Timestamp` are now considered equal.

Comment: Your equal method should include checks for other fields as well

Comment: This is probably not a good idea - if you are using other fields your equals to discard dupe timestamps might not work (assuming other fields are different) and then the usage of `Equals` will be less than intuitive...

Comment: I just forgot to add the other fields to the implementation. Edited the answer.

Comment: Then it no longer removes dupes - so this code is invalid (`InventoryDetailsId` is unique in the OPs question)

Comment: It's the other fields that need to be compared, not `InventoryDetailsId`.