# Select Distinct User ID in a ViewModel List

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm pretty new to MVC so there might be a super simple answer to this.

The following is my current controller code:

```
public class StudentBanController : Controller
{
    SWGS_GlobalDataEntities DataContext = new SWGS_GlobalDataEntities();
    // GET: StudentBan
    public ActionResult DisplayBans()
    {
        var theData = DataContext.tblGlobalLogOnLogOffStudentBans.ToList();


          List<StudentBanDisplayViewModel> BanList = theData
              .Select(viewModel => new StudentBanDisplayViewModel
              {
                  ID = viewModel.ID,
                  UserID = viewModel.UserID,
                  StartBan = viewModel.StartBan,
                  EndBan = viewModel.EndBan
              }).Where(b => b.EndBan > DateTime.Today).ToList();

        return PartialView(BanList);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is create a list, but I only want it to contain records for Distinct UserID's and I cant figure how to do it.

I have tried .distinct in various places and also grouping by user ID and selecting .first but nothing seems to do the job.

Any advice?

Comment: If all you just want a List of userids in your view and nothing else, you could create a List<int> of user ids and return it to your view,making sure your view is now bound to that type,or you could create a new viewmodel with userids as a property(binding to view models recommended) and bind your view to it.However if you need to bind the view to the StudentBanDisplayViewModel and still need the other info this object hold,and you want a separate list of user ids,say for a dropdown list or something, you could put them in a view bag? Or add them to your existing StudentBanDisplayViewModel

Comment: To clarify, I need all of the data. The list populates a table in the partialview and at the moment there are multiple table rows per user. I want to filter it so that each user ID only appears once.

Comment: And do you have multiple rows in your table : tblGlobalLogOnLogOffStudentBans for the user ?

Comment: You could create a View, which makes use of PARTITION BY USERID (assuming your using tsql) and then only select where Partition value = 1

Comment: Yeah, and I cant really change the table because it apparently breaks the whole banning system if I do...

Comment: otherwise create a new List<T> and add the items to that list by checking first if it is in that list or not

Comment: Take a look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983618/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-collection-using-iequalitycomparer-linq-distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
 List<StudentBanDisplayViewModel> BanList = theData
          .Select(viewModel => new StudentBanDisplayViewModel
          {
              ID = viewModel.ID,
              UserID = viewModel.UserID,
              StartBan = viewModel.StartBan,
              EndBan = viewModel.EndBan
          }).Where(b => b.EndBan > DateTime.Today)
            .DistinctBy(s => new {s.UserID}).ToList();
```

[How to remove duplicates from collection using IEqualityComparer, LinQ Distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983618/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-collection-using-iequalitycomparer-linq-distinct)

You will require the following
https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs?r=d4396b9ff63932be0ab07c36452a481d20f96307