# Removing duplicates from a list<int,int>

Tags: c#

I am parsing an input file and after processing the input i am receiving the following output:

```
(0,-1)
(0,0)
(0,-1)
(0,0)
(0,-1)
(0,0)
(0,-1)
(0,0)
```

I need to remove the duplicates and have a count of distinct points.

I am using a list

`List<CoOrds> visitedHouses = new List<CoOrds>();`

where

```
class CoOrds
{
public int X;
public int Y;

public CoOrds()
        {
            X = 0;
            Y = 0;
        }

}
```

I tried to use the following `visitedHouses.Distinct().Count()`, but it does not return the solution that is expected.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: try overiding the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of `CoOrds` to cehck the values

Comment: Needs CoOrds to be class? A struct could be an alternative that makes comparing easier. I could assume that visitedHouses.Distinct() then will work.

Comment: While linked question's accepted answer based on `IEqualityComparer`, I'd recommend you to use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16983700/580053 if you will leave `CoOrds` as a class, but, actually, @xforfun 's suggestion is a best alternative - your "class" has value type semantic.

Comment: Personally, I'd use a dictionary instead of a list. Check for existence before adding new items, and you get a unique list out of your import process without any further work.

If you need the duplicate data too, you can pass out both a list and a dictionary from your import code.

Implement a property on your CoOrds class which returns a key which is unique to the object. For example: return = string.Format("{0},{1}", X, Y);

use that property as the key in the dictionary, and you'll be able to do it quickly and easily.