# EntityFramework Group by not included in SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, group-by

I'm trying to create a query similar to this:

```
select randomId 
from myView
where ...
group by randomId
```

NOTE: EF doesn't support the *distinct* so I was thinking of going around the lack of it with the *group by* (or so I think)

> randomId is numeric
>
> Entity Framework V.6.0.2

This gives me the expected result in < 1 second query

When trying to do the same with EF I have been having some issues.

If I do the LINQ similar to this:

```
context.myView
.Where(...)
.GroupBy(mt => mt.randomId)
.Select({ Id = group.Key, Count = group.Count() } )
```

I will get sort of the same result but forcing a *count* and making the query > 6 seconds

The SQL EF generates is something like this:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1],
[GroupBy1].[K1] AS [randomId],
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2]
FROM ( 
SELECT 
     [Extent1].[randomId] AS [K1],
     COUNT(1) AS [A1]
     FROM [dbo].[myView] AS [Extent1]
     WHERE (...)
     GROUP BY [Extent1].[randomId]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

But, if the query had the count commented out it would be back to < 1 second

If I change the Select to be like:

```
.Select({ Id = group.Key} )
```

I will get all of rows without the *group by* statement in the SQL query and no *Distinct* whatsoever:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[anotherField] AS [anotherField], -- 'this field got included automatically on this query and I dont know why, it doesnt affect outcome when removed in SQL server'
[Extent1].[randomId] AS [randomId]
FROM [dbo].[myView] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (...)
```

Other failed attempts:

```
query.GroupBy(x => x.randomId).Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault());
```

The query that was generated is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].ALL FIELDS,...
    FROM  (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[randomId] AS [randomId]
        FROM [dbo].[myView] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (...) AS [Project1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent2].ALL FIELDS,...
        FROM [dbo].[myView] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE (...) AS [Limit1] -- same as the where above
```

This query performed rather poorly and still managed to return all Ids for the where clause.

Does anyone have an idea on how to force the usage of the *group by* without an aggregating function like a count?

In SQL it works but then again I have the distinct keyword as well...

Cheers,
J

Comment: Just verified - if only grouping key is selected, then DISTINCT query is generated with default EF provider for MS SQL

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I have that currently with **query.GroupBy(x => x.randomId).Select(group => new { ID = group.Key }).ToList()**
And I get duplicated "randomId" values in the output.
Also, glimpse query does not show the *Distinct* nor the *group by*

Comment: Maybe you think that values are duplicated? E.g. check white spaces. Also *distinct* should exist in generated query

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8560928/3411327): use Select( new { Id = group.FirstOrDefault()} )

Comment: The randomId is a numeric column, therefore I cannot have spaces and the query still doesn't have the distinct.

Editing post to say the EF version I am using!

Comment: @user3411327 that made the query even worse.
Will update post with the outcome so everyone is made aware

Comment: @JSilva well, I have EF version 6.0.0.0 but I don't think thats the issue. Also including `[anotherField]` in result looks strange to me. Make sure grouping is applied.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy That is why I had to come here with my question. It's getting to bizarre. I might create a sample project at home and try to reproduce it there and post case its also _broken_

Comment: Why do you say there is no `Distinct`? `query.Select(o => o.randomId).Distinct()` should work just fine.

Comment: Hello guys, sorry for the delay but here is the problem/answer. While I was only working on the server side of things, the view was re-created and some inner / left joins got changed around. That made the query to be faster but since I wasn't aware, most of the mappings done in code where **WRONG** (required, nullable, etc) and that triggered the EF to not create the query correctly.

Now, the fields didn't change but the problem got fixed after reviewing the property mappings and the distinct is now on the query.

Didn't investigate any further why EF was working all funny when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from p in TableName 
        select new {Id = p.ColumnNameId};
var distinctItems = query.Distinct().ToList();
```

Here is the linq query however you should be able to write an equivalent from EF dbset too. If you have issues let me know.

Cheers!

Comment: I have traced the SQL it generates it is like SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[ColumnNameId] AS [Id]
FROM [TableName] AS [t0]