# C# list pool / remove duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have got a list which looks like this:

```
Id: 1
Line1: Microsoft
Line2: Windows
Line3: Server
Line4: null
Line5: null

Id: 2
Line1: Microsoft
Line2: Windows
Line3: Server
Line4: null
Line5: null

Id: 3
Line1: Microsoft
Line2: Windows
Line3: Server
Line4: Development
Line5: null
```

Now I would like to pool / remove all the duplicates (Id 1 and 2).
How is this possible?

I tried something like this:

```
result = result.DistinctBy(x => x.Line3).ToList();
```

But then it would also remove Id 3 which is not correctly.

**Expected output:**

```
Id: 2              // can also be 1, doesn't matter
Line1: Microsoft
Line2: Windows
Line3: Server
Line4: null
Line5: null

Id: 3
Line1: Microsoft
Line2: Windows
Line3: Server
Line4: Development
Line5: null
```

Comment: What do you mean "pool all the duplicates"?  Show your expected output.

Comment: Sorry for that, I want to remove them. Look at my edit @MrZander

Comment: Does it matter whether you keep 1 or 2 if they are duplicates?

Comment: Yes I need to keep one of them, the Id doesn't matter though @msitt

Comment: What about an `IEqualityComparer` on the object in the list, and call `.Distinct()`?

Comment: How would that work? I am not good with lists @entropic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560884/how-to-implement-iequalitycomparer-to-return-distinct-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is to create a `Tuple` as the grouping object.

```
result = result.GroupBy(r => Tuple.Create(r.Line1, r.Line2, r.Line3, r.Line4, r.Line5))
               .Select(g => g.First())
               .ToList();
```

I do not have `DistinctBy`, but this should work:

```
result = result.DistinctBy(r => Tuple.Create(r.Line1, r.Line2, r.Line3, r.Line4, r.Line5))
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Did it! Thanks boss;)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with your DistinctBy you just need to create an anonymous type with all the fields you care about

```
result = result.DistinctBy(x => new {x.Line1, x.Line2, x.Line3, x.Line4, x.Line5}).ToList();
```